# How do I set up the sources.list to select kernel packages from a local repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, repository, reprepro

I am creating a local repository which will contain all the debians (debs) for Ubuntu. It will also contain kernel debians for 2 different branches like say 1.1 and 2.1

I have created a single empty debian package, say `test-package` which contains information for all other dependent debians from same repo. Currently it has information on kernel 1.1.

Structure of local repo is as follows:

The folder `dists/xenial/release/test-package` contains folders `k`, `l`, `m`, `v` which contain debs.

The folders `binary-amd64` and `binary-i386` are also created which contains Packages file for corresponding architectures.

Steps performed on the client machine:

1. Adding URL in `sources.list`
2. Running command `apt-get install test-package`

My issue is:

How can I inform `sources.list` to pick specific kernel installation and its corresponding debians (debs) available from local repo. i.e. it should install either 1.1 or 2.1 kernel.

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by "debians" in this context?

Comment: I think that by "debians" you mean debian packages, usually referred to on this site as *packages*, or *deb packages*. Is that right? Your question has been flagged as too broad, probably because of the numbered list of requirements. I'm not sure this question really is too broad, but if you [edit] this and remove points 2. and 3. from the list, you might be more likely to get an answer, and you can ask a new question for each of the other points if needed.

Comment: @waltinator debians is usually referred to deb packages.

Comment: @Zanna Thank you for your opinion. Will edit and remove points 2 and 3.

Comment: @PulkitLall but I don't think I have ever heard anyone call deb packages "debians". Also: You don't use `sources.list` to tell apt to prefer one set of packages from a repo over another. That's what `preferences` are for.

Comment: @muru Will preferences be able to install test-package with kernel 1.1 or test-package with 2.1? My aim is to install test-package for kernel 1.1 or 2.1 i.e. when I do sudo apt-get install test-package, I should be able to install 1.1 or 2.1 depending on what I want.

Comment: @PulkitLall for that you can just do `sudo apt-get install test-package=1.1` (or `=2.1`)

Comment: @muru The method mentioned is for test-package version and not for kernel version. Package name is same, only difference is kernel.

Comment: Thanks @muru, your line "sudo apt-get install test-package=1.1" had given me some idea and now am able to install it as required. Had tried your command but it was not what I wanted.

Comment: In that case you can post an answer describing what worked for you.

Comment: **Upvoted both question and answer as this might benefit someone else.  Not really a duplicate**.  If this would be closed, ping me @Fabby and I will start the re-open process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created 2 separate debs for 1.1 and 2.1 and kept in same repo server i.e. In my repo server `dists/xenial/release/test-package` is created and inside this folder in folder 't' I created 2 debs i.e. `test-package-1.1` and `test-package-2.1`.

Added

```
http://[server]/ubuntu/dists xenial/release test-package
```

in `sources.list`.

Now when I run `apt-get install test-package-1.1`, it installs 1.1 package and similarly for 2.1.

Not sure if this is correct approach but it is working for me as desired.